# html elements in php echo aren't there when generated

Tags: php, html, tags, echo

I'm having a bit of trouble styling my database query results because, for some reason, the HTML elements I'm echoing are being stripped out completely when I view the page online. The tags ( and , etc) aren't commented, just completely gone when viewing the source of the page.

The idea of this script is for it to get the voting results of players. Using the current script, the data all shows up, so there isn't a connection issue. Here's the php I've got currently:

```
<?php

$user_name = "TAKEN OUT";
$password = "TAKEN OUT";
$database = "TAKEN OUT";
$server = "TAKEN OUT";
$db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password);
$db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);

if ($db_found) {

$SQL = "SELECT * FROM votesql ORDER BY votes DESC";
$result = mysql_query($SQL);
$value = 1;
while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo "<tr id=\"voterank\">" . $value . "</div>";
echo "<td id=\"vote-place\">" . $value . "</td>";
echo "<td id=\"vote-playername\">" . $db_field['playername'] . "</td>";
echo "<td id=\"vote-count\">" . $db_field['votes'] . "</td>";

$value = $value + 1;

echo ("</tr>");
}

mysql_close($db_handle);

}
else {
print ("Database NOT Found ");
mysql_close($db_handle);
}

?>
```

This results in a page displaying information very similar to this:

11Playerone1222Playertwo11261

When I view the source of the page, it is shown as a simple block of text with no elements. I've been stuck on this for the past 3 hours (not even exaggerating) trying to find how I can echo this out, but with no luck. I've also tested this on two different hosting environments, one on my machine via EasyPHP, and the other via a site that I own.

Any help fixing this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: BTW - mysql is deprecated. New projects should be using mysqli or PDO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`td`s require a complete table structure:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>Column 1 </td>
  <td>Column 2 </td>
 <tr>
</table>
```

it could be that the browser is cutting out the `<td>` elements in your case because they're invalid without a surrounding`<table>`.

Also, as [Mike W points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17131118/187606), you're closing the `<tr>` with a `</div>`, while you shouldn't close anything at that point.

You should be seeing your original HTML in the real "view source" view, though.

Comment: Ahh, didn't know about the table tags being required, thanks for that. And yep, I just checked the source via "view source" and sure enough, it was there - I was using chrome's element inspector.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<tr id=\"voterank\">" . $value . "</div>";
```

You need a TD here, and the `</div>` is wrong.

Also, you're repeating the id in each `<td>` in each row. IDs should be unique on the page. Maybe you use `class="..."` here instead.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice I hadn't changed that to a </tr>. Must've been from staring at the same code for too long, haha. And yeah, I'll change them to classes instead. Thanks!

Comment: *removed, the </div> not changed (just passed the 5 minute edit timeframe)

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
echo "<tr id=\"voterank\">" . $value . "</div>";
echo "<td id=\"vote-place\">" . $value . "</td>";
echo "<td id=\"vote-playername\">" . $db_field['playername'] . "</td>";
echo "<td id=\"vote-count\">" . $db_field['votes'] . "</td>";
```

to:

```
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td id=\"voterank\">" . $value . "</td>";
echo "<td id=\"vote-place\">" . $value . "</td>";
echo "<td id=\"vote-playername\">" . $db_field['playername'] . "</td>";
echo "<td id=\"vote-count\">" . $db_field['votes'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: This will fix the tag issue, but the `id` should be unique on the page. This repeats them on each row.

Comment: why don`t you use class instead of id?

Answer (score 0):

A little simple:

```
echo '<tr>
<td id="voterank">'.$value'.</td>
<td id="vote-place">'.$value.'</td>
<td id="vote-playername">'.$db_field['playername'].'</td>;
<td id="vote-count">'.$db_field['votes'].'</td>
</tr>';
```

If you begin echo with single quotes, you won't need use (/) before double quotes. Good luck.